# Continuous Data Protection on Openbsd

Tags: backup, web-server, openbsd

I was wondering if there is anything similar to [Continuous Data Protection](http://www.r1soft.com/linux-cdp/) that is available for openbsd?

Answer (score 3):

Aieeeee! My eyes! Business jargon overload!

Ahem.

I mean -- that's the first time I heard of this *Continous Data Protection*. I wonder if for example [rdiff-backup](http://www.nongnu.org/rdiff-backup/) driven from cron every X minutes/hours could do the trick for you? It's simple, easy to install and straight to the point.

How much data you have to backup and how often? rsync is such a proven work-horse it probably can do the job for you.

Or, in other words: *rsync is an enterprise-grade file synchronization and backup solution for your emerging business needs. It is used around the globe in the most demanding mission-critical environments.*

**EDIT:** Oh, CDP provides a web interface. How about [BackupPC](http://backuppc.sf.net/), then? You really need to describe the feature set you need.

(Sorry for my allergy towards the commercial solutions. Probably the product you are talking about is a nice one, but too many times I've seen some slideware that promises to do everything, but in the real world the final product is a very heavy, buggy and complex (so no one really understands what's going on behind the scenes) piece of polished turd, yet the price is something unbelievable. :-))

Comment: basically 1 server copies to another one every 15mins. then the 2nd server copies all of that data to an offiste location every day. Near CDP is incrimental backups every 15mins, sort of. That software is the only one for linux but im not sure if it works on bsd or not

Comment: That level of simplicity is easily achievable with a combination of rsync, cron and tar (or whatever you need/want for that off-site location). Or with BackupPC -- it has the Archive Host feature.